# in app purchase auto renewing subscription group downgrade always fails

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

We have an app with 18 products in one subscription group, there are 9 levels each with two products, one 1 month and one 1 year. The products are configured but not yet submitted for review.
We are testing with a sandbox account.
When testing the app there is a single page showing all 18 products, and we can do test purchases from this page.
The issue is that we can only upgrade after selecting the first product. We cannot downgrade or purchase a product at the same level.
The apple server comes back with "cannot connect to the iTunes store", but then we can do another upgrade.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem,upgrade is working but downgrade/same is not working.

Comment: same here, did you find a solution ?

Comment: The downgrade appears to occur once the current purchase has expired.

Comment: Does this mean it works in production?

Comment: It has not been testing in product, yet!

Comment: @iCyberPaul Have you tested in production yet? Would be really good to know what happened :)

Comment: @John Sorry I don't work there any more, and left before it was deployed.

Comment: In case this helps anyone, while my app isn't live yet I'm pretty sure I've ascertained that upgrades/downgrades pretty much **do not work** in the sandbox environment. It's reported in a couple of places that this behaviour is not testable in the sandbox. Naturally, Apple would rather waste 1000s of developer hours than fix this or document it.

Comment: @John I've just recently encountered this issue and wasted entirely too much time trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Your comment has given me hope and confidence that it's not me :)

Comment: two years passed, but it still fails all the time for downgrading the subscription.